# Clear Parent and Keep Transformation

Tags: mesh, transforms, parent

Add a *Plane*, **Rotate** (here on Z axis 45°) ...

[image]

Add an *Empty*, *Parent* the *Plane* to the *Empty* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and *Scale* the *Empty*
(here scale along X axis 0.5)

[image]

The Plane transformation as expected ... but already here the Dimension value is strange.

[image]

Select the *Plane* and **Clear Parent and Keep Transformation** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>.

[image]

Result is weird looking Plane ... not only the *Transformation* wasn't kept, but also original *Rotation* and *Scale* is somehow shifted.

[image]

Note: Empty and Plane with the same rotation (Collection 01 and 03) works fine. Since a "child" is rotated it fails (see Collection 02).

Comment: Scale can not be propagated to children, since Blender doesn't support shearing.

Comment: Leander, I'm not sure what you mean, if you parent a cube to an empty, scale the empty, the cube will scale as well. If you unparent the cube with the Keep Transformation option, it should keep its inherit scale. It's not happening here, why that?

Comment: @moonboots Only if the scaling is uniform on all axes (e.g. `3, 3, 3`). Any "non-uniform" (don't know a better word) scale like `1, 2, 3` combined with a rotation would apply into a sheared matrix, which Blender doesn't support. (Search for [shear](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/computer_graphics/3d_transformation.htm).)

Comment: ok so maybe give a full explanation as answer  ;)

Comment: @ Leander: Scaling 1,2,3 itself doesn't seem to be a problem, so since a child is in angle against a parent, it results in "shearing" transformation, right? But since there is not a problem to transform mesh in some result as child, what's the problem to let blender regenerate vertecies in the same exact position?

Comment: I tried to provide an explanation and a workaround. Is is, unfortunately, both wordy and still requires some previous knowledge. The python code is intended for 2.8, are you using 2.79? If you are using 2.79 you have to replace the matrix multiplication operator `@` with an `*`.

Comment: @ *"What's the problem to let Blender regenerate vertices in the same exact position?"* - I would like to know as well! This is exactly what I would do with the script at the end of my answer. Perhaps someone else knows, where that button is hidden in Blender.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Blender does not support shear or skew transformations, thats why the state you request can not be reached on object/transform level but only on data/mesh level. I have added a possible workaround at the end of the post.

## Translation, Rotation, Scale

First, let's confirm that Blender only supports translation, rotation and scaling transformations. Select the untransformed default cube.

Open up the Blender Python console, type `bpy.context.object.matrix_world` and press enter.

[image: python console, matrix.world]

Cool, we are confronted by 16 numbers of a matrix. `bpy.context.object` is simply a reference to this object. `matrix_world` is the transformation matrix. A transformation matrix contains the objects transformation: *translation*, *rotation*, *resizing*, *shearing* and *skewing*.
Look at [these slides](https://forums.sketchup.com/t/3d-shear-notation/56854) for a brief overview or this [beautifully crafted blog post](https://medium.com/swlh/understanding-3d-matrix-transforms-with-pixijs-c76da3f8bd8) for a more detailled explanation.
The `_world` part in `matrix_world` simply refers to the resulting matrix with all parents transformations applied. Since the default cube has no parents, we could also use `matrix_local`.

We can not only output the matrix of the default, we can also assign it using python. Obviously we usually only work with partial components of the transformation matrix of object (*tranlation, rotation, scale*) since the matrix is not very intuitive. Open Blenders *Text Editor* and paste the following script.

```
import bpy
import mathutils
from math import cos, sin, pi

mat = mathutils.Matrix( [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 1, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1] ])

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.matrix_world = mat
```

Here we assign a matrix to the active object. Pressing <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> or the *Run Script* button will assign this matrix to the cube. We don't see a change, because this is the so called identity matrix, which doesn't transform the object (or it transforms all points in place).
However, we can do simple transformation with a matrix via python code. Here are three examples (for translation, rotation and scale) which you can replace in the above code snippet. The results are seen in the image below.

```
# translate x by -1
mat = mathutils.Matrix( [ [1, 0, 0, -1],
                          [0, 1, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1] ])
# rotate z by pi/8 (~22.5°)
mat = mathutils.Matrix( [ [cos(pi/8), -sin(pi/8), 0, 0],
                          [sin(pi/8), cos(pi/8), 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1] ])
# scale y by 2
mat = mathutils.Matrix( [ [1, 0, 0, 0],
                          [0, 2, 0, 0],
                          [0, 0, 1, 0],
                          [0, 0, 0, 1] ])
```

[image: results]

## Shearing or Skewing

As far as I understand, the following matrix should shear the object along the objects X axis. You may be familiar with Shearing from *Edit Mode*, where you can shear points with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>.

```
[1, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 1, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 1, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

However, in the 3D view, we can see, that assigning this matrix with the code snippet from earlier will only scale and rotate the object. What happened? I guess, Blender is trying to show the transformation in the GUI, converted it to TRS and displayed it in the *Transform* panel. The other parts of the matrix were ignored and the matrix reconstructed without the *shear/skew*.
In fact, if we go into the python console and execute `bpy.context.object.matrix_world` it shows an entirely different matrix, than what we just inserted.

```
<Matrix 4x4 ( 0.9210,  0.5395, 0.1117, 0.0000)
            (-0.3815,  1.1907, 0.5395, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0790, -0.5395, 1.3025, 0.0000)
            ( 0.0000,  0.0000, 0.0000, 1.0000)>
```

## What can happen when unparenting?

When unparenting an object, it can require a transformation matrix, which includes shear/skew and can't be expressed with just TRS.

Let's look at an example, where everything is fine first. The *Empty* is the parent of the *Cube*.
The empty is scaled to `0.5`as can be seen in the Transform panel.
The *Cube* is scaled to `2` on the Y-Axis.
[image: parent-relation]

Even before doing any unparenting, we can figure out, what's going to happen. The Cube must have a scale of `0.5, 1.0, 0.5` to remain in its current transformation.

We can also figure this out, by multiplying the matrices.

```
[ 0.5 0   0   0    ]         [ 1   0   0   0    ]       [ 0.5 0   0   0  ]
[ 0   0.5 0   0    ]    x    [ 0   2   0   0    ]   =   [ 0   1   0   0  ]
[ 0   0   0.5 0    ]         [ 0   0   1   0    ]       [ 0   0   0.5 0  ]
[ 0   0   0   1    ]         [ 0   0   0   1    ]       [ 0   0   0   1  ]
```

This is the same as what Blender would tell us when calling `matrix_world` of the child *Cube*.

```
>>> bpy.data.objects['Cube'].matrix_world
Matrix(((0.5, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.5, 0.0),
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)))
```

---

In this second case the cube is rotated by an angle which is not a multiple of 90° and the empty has a non-uniform scale of `1, 0.5, 0.5`.

[image: transformations]

```
[ 1   0   0   0    ]         [ 0.7 1.4 0   0    ]       [ 0.7 1.4 0   0  ]
[ 0   0.5 0   0    ]    x    [-0.7 1.4 0   0    ]   =   [-0.3 0.7 0   0  ]
[ 0   0   0.5 0    ]         [ 0   0   1   0    ]       [ 0   0   0.5 0  ]
[ 0   0   0   1    ]         [ 0   0   0   1    ]       [ 0   0   0   1  ]
```

Even though we can't see it in the numbers, we end up with a transformation matrix which is not representable with only translation, rotation and scale.
Unparenting the cube results in it's shear changing.
[image: needed scale]
And it's obvious, that we can't scale the right cube towards the shape of the left. We need to scale along the **green arrow**, but there is no axis of the cube which points in that direction. If the rotations were done at 90° angles, this would not be a problem. Again ...

#### Most transformations can not be reached using only location, rotation and scale.

But wait, right **before** unparenting, we were able to see the correct transformation matrix using matrix_world of the child *Cube*, right? Yes, and that is a way to "apply" the transformation to the points.

## What happens to the matrix when unparenting?

How does the matrix change when unparenting since shear and skew are ignored?

[image: matrix values]

We can reproduce this process by extracting TRS from `matrix_world` with python and the `mathutils module`.

1. Get the `matrix_world` of the child *Cube*.
2. Extract the location, rotation and scale using the the matrix' `decompose()` function.
3. Assemble a new matrix from the location, rotation and scale.

The result will be the same matrix as the one we receive, when we unparent the Cube. It is different from the original matrix.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

mat = bpy.context.object.matrix_world

loc, rot, sca = mat.decompose()

mat_loc = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(loc)
mat_rot = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
mat_sca = mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4)
mat_sca[0][0], mat_sca[1][1], mat_sca[2][2] = sca

mat_out = mat_loc @ mat_rot @ mat_sca
print(mat_out)
```

We **want** the points of the mesh to be transformed by the original `mat`, but we are left with the reduced `mat_out` after the transformation.

## The Workaround

We want to apply the missing transformation directly to the points, so that the unparented resulting transformation matrix is "enough" to reproduce the original transformation.
Using the naming from the previous code snippet:

```
mat_out @ mat_h = mat
```

`mat_h` is the missing part of the transformation, which is needed to return to the original transformation (`mat`). We can get it's value with the following line:

```
mat_h = mat_out.inverted() @ mat
```

And we can apply this to the cube, **before** unparenting is with a short script.

```
import bpy
import mathutils

ob = bpy.context.object
mat = ob.matrix_world

loc, rot, sca = mat.decompose()

mat_loc = mathutils.Matrix.Translation(loc)
mat_rot = rot.to_matrix().to_4x4()
mat_sca = mathutils.Matrix.Identity(4)
mat_sca[0][0], mat_sca[1][1], mat_sca[2][2] = sca

mat_out = mat_loc @ mat_rot @ mat_sca
mat_h = mat_out.inverted() @ mat

# Unparent the object.
bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')

# Move the vertices to their original position,
# which the mat_out can't represent.
for v in ob.data.vertices:
    v.co = mat_h @ v.co
```

Paste this script in Blenders script editor and press **Run Script** or <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>. It will unparent the mesh and apply the transformations, which can no longer be represented by location, rotation and scale, directly to the points.

Comment: Killing answer !!! :) You are number one, I hope you are in touch with devs, so there is a chance to get the result natively without workarrounds. Works in glance. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thank you for your kind words! While this would probably be a cool feature, I think that it wouldn't be intuitive if unparenting changed your vertices (at geometry level).

Comment: So what about to rename it to “Clear Parent and Apply Transformation”?  Like that transformation can be applied on object level as well (now it is a mix). Seems to me clear, right? Or add it as a new operator, because like now - end user primarily needs object in specific shape. Current blenders posibilities does not fits to this.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me and I wanted to share small tip which was solution for me.

Check it if you have keys on it. It applies the key position.

If you need to unparent more than one object, then be sure that you are in *Dope Sheet* instead of *Action Editor*. You can click to arrow to see only what you select and delete all the keys on them.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't use any keyframes ... or I didnt understand your tip.