# How to remove Parent of an object using python while preserving transformation

Tags: parent

My question is how to clear parent of an particular object lets say its name is 'Cube'.
I don't want to use

```
bpy.ops.object.parent_clear(type='CLEAR_KEEP_TRANSFORM')
```

Because this only clear parents for the selected objects. and that is not my case. as I want to remove parents of objects with particular name and also keep the transformation. Is there any method without the above line of code.

And also I want to do it with a code not using Alt+P, thank you.

Comment: `obj.parent = None` ? https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.parent

Comment: I updated my question. lets say the parent of the object is 'a' if a has some uniform scale. and when I use the line u suggested it clears the parent but it doesn't preserve the transformation which I need

Comment: [Clear Parent and Keep Transformation](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/154848/clear-parent-and-keep-transformation)

Comment: actually I found another way. If you apply transform of the parent object and then set obj.parent=None. then it keeps the transformation. Can u tell me a code for applying scale and rotation without using bpy.ops.object.transform_apply(location=False, rotation=False, scale=True)