# Programatically unparenting an rigid body doesn't work (with file)

Tags: python, animation, scripting, keyframes, parent

I parented a rigid body to another rigid body. The parent rigid body is keyframed. I want to remove the parent and any lingering keyframing from that parent. Programatically, I tried to remove the parenting from the child rigid body. It works perfectly in viewport, but not at all when scripting.

What I've tried goes something like this:

```
    if bpy.context.scene.frame_current == 50: 
       bpy.data.objects['ChildObj'].select = True
       bpy.ops.objects.parent_clear(type='CLEAR')
       bpy.data.objects['ChildObj'].select = False
```

Another thing that may contribute is that the parent rigid body is a compound parent.

In my case, the issue is happening from line 118-122.
The file is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1lpJHC5SdOq553Y3tp-Cc-3QpWQAwQDcj/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I believe this method of selecting objects is deprecated since V2.80. Which version are you using ?

Comment: The current way to remove the parent is to simply set it to none, ie `bpy.data.objects['ChildObj'].parent = None`  You don't need to select or deselect it.

Comment: This worked for me on 3.0.0 , thank you!

Comment: @MartyFouts, if I wanted to clear but keep transform, how would that work programatically, thanks in advance!

Comment: Ah, see [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/154926/42221)  basically, you need to apply the transform manually.